# How to convert a png into pdf using LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, pdf, paper-size, png

I have a larger png image: width is 5400 pixels and height is 3850 pixels. I need to transform it into a pdf file in SPA3 size, which means 320mm x 450mm. Is there a way to do it with LaTeX? What I think I need, is to be able to specify the paper size explicitly and to tell LaTeX that there should not be anything around the image.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Peter Grill, thank you. I am here just few minutes and it already saved me hours of search and work! :)

Comment: Isn't it **SRA3** according to [Paper size/Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [the `standalone` class](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) which will produce a pdf with no border. If you want a small border you can add `[border=<length>]` class option.

### Notes:

- As LionelMANSUY mentioned in the comments it is usually preferable to use `keepaspectratio`, but if specific dimensions of *both* height and width are required, using `` `keepaspectratio ``  may conflict with those requirements..

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width=320mm,height=450mm]{../images/EiffelWide}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly! I love stackexchange. It works so fast and so effective (of course because of its users).

Comment: Your welcome.. But keep in mind this is TeX.SE -- I think this site is a whole lot friendlier than your regular stackexchange. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill Is it not preferable to append also the `keepaspectratio` option?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: Well yes, but since both the height _and_ width are fixed amounts, not sure it makes sense to also specify `keepaspectratio`?

Comment: @PeterGrill If I don't mistake, when you write both height and width, you will have a disproportionated picture if the values are not proportional to the source picture's ones. Here: 5400/3850=1.403 and 450:320:1.406; the difference is here negligible but still exist

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: Yes, but the question asked to get an image of a specific size -- I assumed that that was what was desired, and not an approximation. I personally would prefer `keepaspectratio`.  Have added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Media size (SRA3): 320mm x 450mm
Image size: 5400px x 3850px

- Media or image needs to be rotated to prevent severe distortion of the image (`keepaspectratio=false`) or larger margins (`keepaspectratio=true`).
- Package `geometry` can be used to set the paper size and package `pdfpages` also works with images.
- If the image is rotated, then package `pdflscape` tells the PDF viewer to rotate the viewed page.
- After rotation the ratios are 1.40625 vs. 1.4026. The difference is quite small, depending on the image and application distortion of the image might be acceptable to avoid a small margin otherwise.
- The margin area can be colored using `\pagecolor` of package `graphics` (also loaded by package `pdfpages`).

Some examples that uses a [`lolcat.jpg`](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg) from a StackExchange error page (also found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/25039)).

### Media rotation without distortion, black margins

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=320mm,
  paperheight=450mm,
  landscape,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagecolor{black}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf{lolcat.jpg}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Cat on rotated media with black margins]

### Image rotation with distortion

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=320mm,
  paperheight=450mm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
    \includepdf[
      angle=90,
      keepaspectratio=true,
      width=\paperwidth,
      height=\paperheight
    ]{lolcat.jpg}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Rotated cat with distortion]

Comment: Isn't it time you bought your cat a new computer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle AFAIK the cat is from StackExchange. Some image that is shown in case of errors.

Comment: @David's cat uses Vim. `:)`